# Alternative to Struts 2 message resource bundle

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am migrating an application from `Struts 1.1` to `Struts 2.3`. 
The existing application uses `MessageResources` from the older framework in the following manner.

```xml
<message-resources key="label" parameter="com.abc.xyz.resources.MyLabelResources"/>
<message-resources key="image" parameter="com.abc.xyz.resources.MyImageResources"/>
```

This way different resources files are separated out and whenever a look-up is done, the bundle key is specified so that it searches in that particular file only.

Based on my understanding on `Struts 2.2` framework, I have concluded that I need a global properties file which will do the work for me. However, I would want to create multiple global properties file say for labels and images like the way its working in the existing application (above).

I am not sure how I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search in particular file only then you can use [`<s:i18n>`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/i18n.html) tag.

Using `getText` method if your action extends `ActionSupport`

```
<s:i18n name="labels">
  <s:property value="getText('some.label')" />
</s:i18n>
```

or using `<s:text>` tag

```
<s:i18n name="labels">
  <s:text name="some.label" />
</s:i18n>
```

But you can also include more than one properties files to custom default resource bundles:

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="images, labels" />
```

Comment: What are images and labels in this case?

Comment: @shabeena: Properties files (e.g. images.properties, labels.properties).

Comment: Ok got that.And how can I specify which file I want to look-up to?

Comment: @shabeena: If you really need to specify specific file then use `<s:i18n>` tag.

Comment: Yes can be done in this manner.                                 <s:i18n name="images">
<s:property value="text('aaa.bbb.ccc')" />
</s:i18n>.                                                              The existing application also uses the MessageResources via a MessageHelper custom class  to read from these resources. In that case, is there a way I can replace that?

Comment: Is there a way to access the resource without the UI tags? I need to retrieve the resource name in some helper class, which certainly does not have a UI tag.

Comment: Do you mean something like `java.util.ResourceBundle`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`i18n` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/i18n-tag.html)

> Gets a resource bundle and place it on the value stack. This allows the text tag to access messages from any bundle, and not just the bundle associated with the current action.

to load the resource bundle to the value stack and use it.

---

Like in [this](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/I18n.html) example.

> Gets a resource bundle and place it on the value stack. This allows
> the text tag to access messages from any bundle, and not just the
> bundle associated with the current action.
>
> ```jsp
> name* - the resource bundle's name (eg foo/bar/customBundle)
> ```
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```jsp
>  <s:i18n name="myCustomBundle">
>     The i18n value for key aaa.bbb.ccc in myCustomBundle is <s:property value="text('aaa.bbb.ccc')" />
>  </s:i18n>
>
>  <s:i18n name="some.package.bundle" >
>       <s:text name="some.key" />
>  </s:i18n>
> ```

---